# Serialized Dataset looses custom data types in columns

Tags: c#, serialization, dataset

I am passing a Dataset through WCF and/or serializing it in a session manager. 
Data disappears from custom columns after deserializing the object. I can verify the data is there before the object is serialized. The custom object is used for implementing alpha numeric sorting and it uses the [Serializable] attribute. The dataset is not strongly typed.

Solution to follow...

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to pass `DataSet` or other .NET-specific types over a web service. It only makes sense if the other side will _always_ be running a compatible version of .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom datatypes can be serialized in a dataset but they require the IXmlSerializable interface be implemented.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

  [Serializable]
  public class AlphaNumericSort : IComparable, IXmlSerializable
  {
...
    // Xml Serialization Infrastructure 
    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(_Value);
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        _Value = reader.ReadString();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return(null);
    }
```

Comment: `[Serializable]` is ignored by the XML Serializer.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good practice to pass dataset or datatable.
So, iterate on your datatable in dataset and fill custom class or class collection that you will serialize (don't forget to set datacontract and datamember attributes)

Comment: I realize it is not best practice but sometimes you have to make the best with what you have. This also applies datasets that are used with session state servers.

Comment: I'm curious why it is a good practice to introduce your own container for passing data when a perfectly servicable one already exists?